# AngularFire2 FirebaseListObservable not always updating

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 `2.0.0-beta.7` with Angular `2.3.1`. I'm pretty new to using both Angular and Firebase so I'm not sure if this is an issue with the way I'm doing this or it's a bug?

In the realtime db I have `events` and `attendees`. You can attend/unattend events. Pretty simple stuff.

If you're not attending an event already, you can attend/unattend as often as you like and it works as expected, the db and list of attendees are updated fine.

The issue I'm experiencing is that if you're already attending you can unattend ok, however, if you try and attend again the db is updated but not the list of attendees. If I refresh the page or navigate away and back again the list is updated as expected.

Below is the code from the component. You can also see a [video showing the issue here](http://cloud.shar.pe/j1x0).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>
      {{(event | async)?.name}}
    </h1>

    <button (click)="attend()">Attend</button> <button (click)="unattend()">unattend</button>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let attendee of attendees | async">
        {{attendee.$key}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Event';
  eventId: string;
  userId: string;
  event: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  attendees: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventId = '-KcDcCSkb_0zqd-TX6RG';
    this.userId = 'LupQbOKjmrSTKgri1eUr7WckJL13';

    this.event = this.af.database.object(`events/${this.eventId}`);
    this.attendees = this.af.database.list(`attendees/${this.eventId}`);
  }

  attend() {
    this.af.database.object(`attendees/${this.eventId}/${this.userId}`).set(true);
  }

  unattend() {
    this.attendees.remove(`${this.userId}`)
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

OK, it's a bug in the AngularFire2 library and has been fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/775)